get miniseed data from seedlink using socket with flutter/dart
i try to connect to seedlink using socket and try listen to get data like waveform from station, there not much example how to do it in code specifically in dart/flutter, i try send basic command from https://docs.fdsn.org/projects/seedlink/en/latest/protocol.html#commands and just return "OK" and no other data.
i try
void sendCommand() {
    if (socket == null) {
      return;
    }
    socket.writeln('DATA\n');
    socket.writeln('SELECT ?????\n');
    socket.writeln('STATION HGN NL\n');
    socket.writeln('END');
  }

  void connectToSeedLink() async {
    if (socket != null) {
      socket.flush();
    }
    // Connect to SeedLink server
    socket = await Socket.connect('eida.orfeus-eu.org', 18000);

    // Send initial SeedLink HELLO command
    socket.writeln('HELLO\n');
    socket.writeln('CAT\n');

    // Listen for data from server
    socket.listen((data) {
      print(data.length);
      final response = utf8.decode(data);
      print('Data from SeedLink: $response');

      sendCommand();
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('Error: $error');
    }, onDone: () {
      print('Connection closed');
      socket.close();
    });
  }

response example :
I/flutter ( 4062): Data from SeedLink: OK
I/flutter ( 4062): 8
I/flutter ( 4062): Data from SeedLink: OK
I/flutter ( 4062): OK
I/flutter ( 4062): 4
I/flutter ( 4062): Data from SeedLink: OK
I/flutter ( 4062): 4

